# Distinguishing multiple docker containers on one Mac

Tags: docker, azure-data-studio

I have made two Docker containers using:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=Password1234" -p1433:1433 --name sql2019 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:vNext-CTP2.0-ubuntu
```

and I distinguished them by changing the `-p` and `--name` section, but when I go over to Azure Data Studio and connect, I can only connect to one of them, because I enter 'localhost' in the `Server` section, but since both containers use 'localhost', how can I differentiate the two in Azure Data Studio? Is there any way to use the `--name` flag?

[image: azure-data-studio-connection-details]

I would appreciate a clear answer; I am new to server stuff.

Comment: The way to distinguish them would be the different port. Does the tool allow to specify another port (maybe in the "Advanced" section)?

Comment: @Henry Yes it does, and it does work. Thanks for your help!